# Scroll text left to right and back

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this line which works fine for showing text in 3 lines starting at 0.3sec, ending at 0.6 sec. in bottom left corner.

I would like to add scroll in and scroll out effect in ffmpeg.

Both in and out should be fast, lets say .05sec.

Scroll in should end in position like its written in code, remaining there for those 3 sec, then scrolling out.

ffmpeg -i scrollin.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=enable='between(t,3,6)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline1':x=10:y=h-th-130, drawtext=enable='between(t,3,6)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline2':x=10:y=h-th-75, drawtext=enable='between(t,3,6)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline3':x=10:y=h-th-20[out]" -codec:a copy scrollout.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this filter expression:

```
"drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='ariblk.ttf': \
text='textline1':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-130"
```

The above is for the first line. I've changed the values/expression for the `enable` and `x`parameters. The movement starts at 2.5 seconds, settles at 3s, stays till 6s and then disappears by 6.5

Comment: This worked perfectly :) Added the expression to all lines. Now i am trying to add drawbox that should go under text like from http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/ffmpeg-drawtext-filter-create-transparent-background-with-text but when i add the expression i get error "too many inputs specified for the "drawtext" filter. Maybe i write this problem to new question ?

Comment: Yes, make it a new question and include the full command you're using.

Comment: Here it is: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/add-transparent-background-to-ffmpeg-with-text-over-it

Comment: Sorry, miscklicked !